# Loop through arguments of a function

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

When I'm trying to create a loop for a object oriented approach (I think) php prompts me with 2 errors. I think it has to do something that a array (`$args`) can't be used on on a place where I should inject a string, but I can't find the answer. Should I run a foreach loop inside a foreach?

**This is the case:**

I have a file named **themeScripts.php** in which I return an `array();` like so:

```
return array(

        'custom' => array(
            'src'           => '/includes/js/custom.js',
            'deps'          => 'jquery',
            'ver'           => '4.0',
            'in_footer'     => true     
        ),
        'selecter' => array(
            'src'           => '/includes/js/jquery.fs.selecter.min.js' 
            'deps'          => 'jquery' 
            'ver'           => false,
            'in_footer'     => true
        )
    );
```

After this I want to run a foreach loop so I could define a loop of the function `wp_enqueue_script` like this:

```
public function loadScripts() {

        // Include themeScripts from config
        $themeScripts = include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../config/themeScripts.php");

        // Loop trough each themeScript
        foreach($themeScripts as $handle => $args):

            wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $args);

        endforeach;

    }
```

> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   /Users/username/Sites/sitename/public_html/themename/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php
>   on line 128
>
> Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /Users/username/Sites/sitename/public_html/themename/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php
>   on line 128

Comment: Here's the [reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) of the function wp_enqueue_script which states the parameters respectively as `string - string - array - string - boolean`. While you are passing the second parameter as an array. Not sure why the first parameter is being passed as array though.

Comment: So I should somehow manipulate the outcome of $args that it correspondents with the parameters in your comment.

Comment: Yes, i think here you could do something like - 
`wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $args['src'], array($args['deps']), $args['ver'], $args['in_footer']);`

Comment: @Shazzad Could you post your comment as a answer? That way I can resolve it. :) See  [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)

Answer (score 0):

[wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) states the parameters type respectively as 
`string - string - array - string - boolean`. As you pass an array as the second parameter, the error occurs.

Now, comparing your $array data, you can handle it extracting the array or using array key/value. -

```
public function loadScripts()
{
    $themeScripts = iarray(
        'custom' => array(
            'src'           => '/includes/js/custom.js',
            'deps'          => 'jquery',
            'ver'           => '4.0',
            'in_footer'     => true     
        ),
        'selecter' => array(
            'src'           => '/includes/js/jquery.fs.selecter.min.js' 
            'deps'          => 'jquery' 
            'ver'           => false,
            'in_footer'     => true
        )
    );

    foreach( $themeScripts as $handle => $args ):

        extract($args);

        wp_enqueue_script( 
            $handle, 
            $src, 
            array($deps), 
            $ver, 
            $in_footer
        );

    endforeach;
}
```